# MongoDB index direction 1 vs true

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Are these indexes redundant?

```
"1" : {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "thing-id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "action-id_1",
    "ns" : "mydatabase.things"
},
"2" : {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "thing-id" : true
    },
    "name" : "action-id_",
    "ns" : "mydatabase.things"
},
```

If not, what is the difference between 1 and true?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a difference - true works the same as 1 in this case. You can test this as follows:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "a" : 1 })
> db.test.insert({ "a" : 2 })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "a" : true })
> db.test.find().sort({ "a" : 1 }).explain().cursor
BtreeCursor a_true
> db.test.find().sort({ "a" : -1 }).explain().cursor
BtreeCursor a_true reverse
```

Since the index was reverse iterated when used to sort in descending order, it's an ascending order index.

You can use all kinds of stupid values in the index specification:

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "a" : null })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "a" : MaxKey })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "a" : 0 })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "a" : /^yogurt$/i })
```

You'd have to test which kind of index each of these give you - it doesn't error out and say it's repeating an index, either, because the indexes get different names. They're likely all ascending for "truthy" values. The related issue seems like [SERVER-769](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-769), which just hasn't been gotten around to, apparently.

The point is, use 1 or -1 or a string option like "text".